# Failed to pull image pull access denied , repository does not exist or may require 'docker login':

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I've created my own image just called `v2` but when I do `kubectl get pods`, it keeps erroring out...`with Failed to pull image "v2": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for v2, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied`
I'm using minukube by the way

This is my deployment file, also called v2.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: v2
spec:
  selector:
    name: v2
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 80
---
# ... Deployment YAML definition
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: v2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: v2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: v2
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: v2
          image: v2
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
---
# ... Ingress YAML definition
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: v2
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /second
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: v2
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

any help gratefully received

Answer (score 12):

My suspicion is that you have built your container image against your local Docker daemon, rather than minikube's. Hence, because your `imagePullPolicy` is set to `IfNotPresent`, the node will try pulling it from Docker hub (the default container registry).

You can run `minikube ssh` to open a shell and then run `docker image ls` to verify the image is not present in the minikube Docker daemon.

The solution here is to first run the following command from your local shell (i.e. not the one in minikube):

```
$ eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)
```

It will set up your current shell to use minikube's docker daemon. After that, in the **same shell**, rebuild your image. Now when minikube tries pulling the image, it should find it and bring up the pod successfully.

Comment: just done `minikube ssh` and `docker image ls` and you're absolutely right..it isn't there..thanks for this......brilliant

Comment: Hi...I've done it again ..using `PS C:\firstday3\v2> minikube docker-env
You can further specify your shell with either 'cmd' or 'powershell' with the --shell flag.

SET DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://172.24.240.18:2376
SET DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\andre\.minikube\certs
SET MINIKUBE_ACTIVE_DOCKERD=minikube
REM To point your shell to minikube's docker-daemon, run:
REM @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube -p minikube docker-env') DO @%i `    but it doesn't want to put my new images into my minikube daemon..it just keeps putting into my local docker deamon...any suggestions?

Comment: error `PS C:\firstday3\v2> & minikube -p minikube docker-env | Invoke-Expression
You: The term 'You' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
Invoke-Expression: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is an empty string.
Invoke-Expression:
Line |
   1 |  & minikube -p minikube docker-env | Invoke-Expression
     |                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The string is missing the terminator: '.`

Comment: ..finally sussed it  sussed it it's just this `minikube -p minikube docker-env --shell powershell | Invoke-Expression` ... I knew I should have bought a Mac

Comment: @Mick8695 Hmm I have no recent experience with the shell you're using. `minikube -p minikube docker-env` will however output a shell script that may be used to configure the environment appropriately - perhaps you can perform these steps manually for your specific setup?

Comment: Faced the same issue as I was using wrong image name, problem is solved after correcting the image name that I used during deployment creation.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message indicate   `v2, repository does not exist` it is because of `image: v2`  . there is no image available in docker hub with name `v2`. if it is in your repository on docker hub then mention it in the form `<reponame>/v2`.

Comment: hi, thanks for replying...it's not on docker hub...what could I write if it's just my local docker desktop daemon?